# Easiest way to export specific user-generated content?

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm using Drupal 6.x on a site that has many users. There are about 20 "Pro" users that function as authors. I need to export an individual author's posts in order to later import them into WordPress. What might be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Bonus! I also need to export the comments associated with each article, AND change all comment authors to "Anonymous." Should I do that after the export through SQL, or is there an easier way?

I am looking into the Views module, but it's pretty far over my head... I would certainly prefer a simpler solution if that is possible.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I am also concerned about how to export the images that are associated with each post...

Answer (score 1):

Views module is the only solution which makes your task very easy.

1.Simply create a view and add the necessary **fields** you want to export.

2.Add a **display** (data export).

3.In **DATA EXPORT SETTINGS** name your path with .csv extension example data.csv

Finally call the path on your browser. That's it

Another difficult way is to write queries and then create a php code to export the result to csv

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Rama... Hopefully I'll get it to work. I appreciate you giving a little walk through rather than just saying "use Views!"

Comment: It's with pleasure. Let me know if any more doubts.

Comment: So I am able to get a decent output of the user's post nodes, but I can't figure out how to use Views' advanced options such as "Relationships" in order to get all the comments related to each post.

For example, I am taking the fields I need and filtering them by "User X" as author; that gets me this one person's content, but how can I grab the comments, too?

Also, any tips for exporting images from the posts?

Comment: If you want to export images using views, you may get only the path to the image . Generally you can see the path in your database with table name file_managed.